# Add one whitespace at everyline of my txt file

Tags: java

I have this method that can read everything within a file but i need to be able to first add one whitespace before every new char at the beginning of everyline.

Tried to make it as easy as possible but non of it seem to work.

```
private static void write() throws IOException {

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\karwa\\Desktop\\HistoryOfProgramming.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        fw.write(" ");
    }

    fw.close();
}
```

Used bufferedReader aswell that had a whileloop that was reading every line and adding one whitespace for each line but that didn't work either. Ideas?

Comment: What are the contents of your file? Also how are you reading the file? It also looks like your aren't using the data you *read* to write the file again.

Comment: Many words and some other chars + whitespaces. But it should be fine as long as i can add just one whitespace at the beginning of each line.

Comment: But also i would like to not use a specific count of lines. In this code i am actually only counting to 15 lines, i believe that it is count lines anyhow..

Comment: What does " but non of it seem to work." mean?

Comment: Your current code writes 15 consecutive spaces to a file, nothing more. What else have you tried?

Comment: `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\karwa\\Desktop\\HistoryOfProgramming.txt");
  FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\karwa\\Desktop\\HistoryOfProgramming.txt");
  BufferedReader x = new BufferedReader(file);

  while (x.readLine() != null) {
   fw.write(" " + fw);
  }
 }`    This is what i have tried. But this does the same exact thing as the first code...

Comment: @AxwellSmith that code cannot work correctly. What do you think `fw.write(" " + fw);` does?

Answer (score 3):

you have to actualy read the lines and store them, only then can you add whitespace

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("test.txt");

    Scanner fr = new Scanner(file);

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    while (fr.hasNextLine()) {
        lines.add(fr.nextLine());
    }

    PrintStream fw = new PrintStream(file);

    for (String line : lines) {
        fw.println(" " + line);
    }

    fr.close();
    fw.close();
}
```

Comment: Well this worked fine thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Read/write the contents to a string
Use replaceAll("\n", "\n ");